# sh/sed to delete lines from file for docker-compose volume override

Tags: regex, sed, docker-compose, sh

docker-compose allows override files, however if a volume is specified in the first file, for example `volA`, and a volume is specified in the override `volB`, the final result will be `volA` and `volB`.

**I need to write a script to search and delete all volumes in the initial docker-compose file.**

This `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  first-container:
    image: 'alpine'
    ports:
      - '5000'
    volumes:
      - './volA:/etc/volA'
      - './volB:/etc/volB'
  second-container:
    image: 'alpine'
    ports:
      - '5000'
    volumes:
      - './volC:/etc/volC'
      - './volD:/etc/volD'
```

Run `script` to make the `docker-compose.yaml` file become:

```
version: '2'
services:
  first-container:
    image: 'alpine'
    ports:
      - '5000'
  second-container:
    image: 'alpine'
    ports:
      - '5000'
```

I know i'll have to do something along the lines of this, but i'm not quite sure how.

`sed -i '/volume:/d' '' ./docker-compose.yaml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sed is for doing s/old/new, that is all. For anything else use awk:

```
$ awk '$1!="-"{inVol=($1=="volumes:")} !inVol' file
version: '2'
services:
  first-container:
    image: 'alpine'
    ports:
      - '5000'
  second-container:
    image: 'alpine'
    ports:
      - '5000'
```

Explanation as requested in  the comments: Every time the input line doesn't start with `-` we set a variable `inVol` to `1` (true) if the first field on the line is `volumes:` or `0` (false) otherwise. Then for every line we just check `inVol` and if it is true (i.e. we're processing a line that started with `volume:` or a subsequent line that started with `-` before the next line that didn't start with `-`) then `!inVol` is false and so we do nothing, but if `inVol` is false (i.e. we're not in the `volume:` block) then `!inVol` is true and so then we invoke the default action given a true condition which is to print the current line.

Comment: OMG that was so helpful!! can you help me understand how that works? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: I added an explanation to the answer.

Comment: Thank you Ed that was extremely helpful!